# Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server with php 7.3 fails with false error message

Tags: php, sql-server

I have installed Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server as a PECL using: `pecl install pdo_sqlsrv sqlsrv` (Ubuntu 16.04.6, php 7.3, apache).

I've also added:

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

to `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/xx-sqlsrv.ini` and it is properly listed on active modules while checking `phpinfo();` rendered by Apache.

When I try to use the SQLSrv lib, then I'm getting an error:

```php
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1' : file not found [message] => [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1' : file not found ) )
```

However, the file `/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1` exists and is accessible by all:

```sh
ls -al /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2046672 Feb 12 21:08 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1
```

Accessing by `sqlcmd` also returns an error:

```sh
sqlcmd -S <server_ip> -U <user_name> -P <pass>
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1' : file not found.
```

Following some other [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/945), I've checked the dependencies and they seem ok:

```sh
ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd0c14b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4fd9349000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f4fd9141000)
    libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f4fd8f26000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.2 => not found
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f4fd8c54000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f4fd8a0a000)
    libssl.so.1.0.2 => not found
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f4fd8805000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4fd8422000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4fd8119000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4fd7f01000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4fd7ce4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4fd791a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4fd9954000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f4fd76eb000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f4fd74e7000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f4fd72dc000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f4fd70d8000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f4fd6ebd000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there was a wrong package source in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list`. Steps to resolve the problem:

```sh
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt remove msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

Add the correct package source basing on the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

```sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
#Ubuntu 16.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```